# Subtracting value until results reach 0 EXCEL

Tags: excel, vba

I want to subtract a value in $C$2 from 1 until it reaches zero. So if the value is 0.2 the first result should be 1 the second 0.8 and so on. They should be written in cells right under each other.
(Sorry for the explanation I'm having problems uploading a screenshot).

The last value doesn't have to be exactly 0 it should just be the last value before the negative ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you put 1 in Cell B2, and have say 0.17 in C2, then put this in B3

```
=MAX(B2-$C$2,0)
```

and copy it down you will get

```
0.83
0.66
0.49
0.32
0.15
0
0 
0
```

which is what I believe you are after.

If you want to do it via vba, you could calculate how many cells down you need filled, or just loop until you get to less than the value of $c$2